# How to set up a two-sided document with large pictures and margins?

Tags: margins, diagrams

i used a one-sided document with the following geometry content

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3.5cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    outer=6cm,
    inner=2cm,
    heightrounded,
    marginparsep=0.8cm,
    marginparwidth=4.7cm
}
```

to get images to a proper size i used the following code to push the picture inside the margin

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\newgeometry{margin=1.8cm}
...
\restoregeometry
\end{figure}
```

... it looks like:

[image: old]

Now i changed the paper to a two-sided document in the document-class. I also updated the geometry code as follows

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3.5cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    outer=6cm,
    inner=2cm,
    heightrounded,
    marginparsep=0.8cm,
    marginparwidth=4.7cm,
    twoside=true  % <--- !!!!
}
```

But i have some problems with big pictures on even pages:

[image: new]

The image should also be pushed into the margin. Any advice how to change the

```
\newgeometry{margin=1.8cm}
```

command?

Comment: Did you try specifying `lmargin` or `rmargin`? `margin` by itself applies automatically to all the margins.

Comment: I tried both, but nothing changed.
It would be nice, if it automatically applies on both types of pages, odd and even, so i don't have to check all the pictures, whether it's on a even or odd page.

Comment: Try package changepage. with it you can locally change the width for your figure. Package also detect odd/even page and adjust margins properly in asymmetric page layout. See package documentation.

Comment: This does only affect the images (not the caption) and pushes them left or right with a wrong size.

Comment: If you put the caption together with figure inside changepage, the caption should follows position of a figure. my experiences with memoir, which incorporate changepage ability show me, that this should work.

Comment: The caption is within the adjustwidth-environment. Anyway, it don't work. Isn't there an other possibility to give a command that pushes the images to the correct side, no matter if the page is even or odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up using the following code with some examples how to set up the pictures and captions:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3.5cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    outer=6cm,
    inner=2cm,
    heightrounded,
    marginparsep=0.8cm,
    marginparwidth=4.7cm,
    twoside=true,
    hmarginratio=1:1
}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=b}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}

\newcommand*{\figurewidthaddition}{\dimexpr
  \marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
\newsavebox\figurebox

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\section{Testchapter}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \ifthispageodd{\makebox[\textwidth][l]}%
                {\makebox[\textwidth][r]}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{First test figure: \blindtext}
\end{figure}

\Blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \ifthispageodd{\makebox[\textwidth][l]}%
                {\makebox[\textwidth][r]}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{Second test figure: \blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{-\figurewidthaddition}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \ifthispagewasodd\else\raggedleft\fi
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}
      \caption{Third test figure: \blindtext}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{-\figurewidthaddition}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \ifthispagewasodd\else\raggedleft\fi
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}
      \caption{Fourth test figure: \blindtext}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

test






\begin{figure}
  \savebox\figurebox{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}%
  }%
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\figurebox\relax}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \ifthispagewasodd\else\raggedleft\fi
      \usebox\figurebox
    \captionsetup{width=0.8\linewidth}
      \caption{Fifth test figure:jwehfewjf\"uoiewj\"ufoijew\"uoi oewfjewoi iuhew ewpfoijewf epwoifje weoipfj ewfopijwef weopifjew fwepoifjwe fpewoij}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}







\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \savebox\figurebox{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}%
  }%
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\figurebox\relax}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \ifthispagewasodd\else\raggedleft\fi
      \usebox\figurebox
      \caption{Sixth test figure: \blindtext}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So this is basically your MWE?

Comment: BTW, there is a problem in that \ifthispageodd uses the page the float was defined on, not the page it appears on.

Comment: Yes, its a MWE. The problem you mentioned didn't affect my work. I saw some drifts in the images while compiling the first time, but after the second compilation it worked as intended ;)

Comment: You really don't have to change the geometry to put things into the margins.  Use \hspace with a negative distance either before (left margin) or after (to prevent overfull boxes).  \hfill\llap{} will right justify into the left margin, and \rlap{}\hfill\newline will left justify into the right margin.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates left and right shifted images with captions aligned with both the text and with the images.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3.5cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    outer=6cm,
    inner=2cm,
    heightrounded,
    marginparsep=0.8cm,
    marginparwidth=4.7cm,
    twoside=true,
    hmarginratio=1:1
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=b}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}

\newcommand{\widebox}[1]% #1 = contents
{\ifthispageodd{\rlap{#1}\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}}%
{\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}\llap{#1}}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Testchapter}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \widebox{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{First test figure: \blindtext}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}
  \widebox{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{Second test figure: \blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \ifthispageodd{}{\null\hspace{-.2\textwidth}}%
    \begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Fourth test figure: \blindtext}
  \end{minipage}%
  \ifthispageodd{\hspace{-.2\textwidth}}{}%
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \ifthispageodd{}{\null\hspace{-.2\textwidth}}%
  \begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Fourth test figure: \blindtext}
  \end{minipage}%
  \ifthispageodd{\hspace{-.2\textwidth}}{}%
\end{figure}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```